# Delete from a table based on date

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help me with the script which will delete the data older than the particular date.

Thanks

Comment: Clarification would help immensely... maybe let us know how you know how old the date is, the column format and data type, is time an issue, etc.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
delete from YOUR_TABLE where your_date_column < '2009-01-01';
```

This will delete rows from `YOUR_TABLE` where the date in `your_date_column` is older than January 1st, 2009. i.e. a date with `2008-12-31` would be deleted.

Answer (score 28):

Delete data that is 30 days and older

```
   DELETE FROM Table
   WHERE DateColumn < GETDATE()- 30
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use:

```
DELETE FROM tableName
where your_date_column < '2009-01-01';
```

but Keep in mind that the above is really

```
DELETE FROM tableName
    where your_date_column < '2009-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Not

```
 DELETE FROM tableName
        where your_date_column < '2009-01-01 11:59';
```

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty vague.
Do you mean like in SQL:

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE dateColumn < '2007'
```

Answer (score 5):

or an ORACLE version:

```
delete
  from table_name
 where trunc(table_name.date) > to_date('01/01/2009','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: my bad, I read a tag of "sql", sorry