# SQL Server - Deleting rows between a date range using SQL. Date conversion fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sql-delete

```
DELETE FROM BIZ 
WHERE [Orgnl_Cmpltn_Date]
      BETWEEN '2014-02-31'  AND '2014-04-01'
```

This is the `DELETE` statement I wrote. There is an error that says:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I know I have to write the correct date format, but I am not sure how that goes.

This question has not been answered elsewhere because the answers I saw did not specify date format (in the context that I am asking for)

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete from a table based on date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804193/delete-from-a-table-based-on-date)

Comment: Given the error text, I strongly suspect that this is [tag:sql-server], but it would be better for the OP to confirm this first.

Comment: 31st February doesn't exists...

Comment: Don't use BETWEEN for date ranges either, way too dangerous. Do you intend t delete any record with a dates of '2014-04-01' or should these be retained? What should happen if there are values like  '2014-04-01 23:58:12.1234567' ?

Comment: different to what? sure if the data type is date only between would work (assuming 2014-01-01 is to be deleted) but that is an IF you don't need to take if you avoid between. Here is a classic case of when we should avoid between because we do not know the precision.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You wrote 31st of February... Maybe..... that date doesn't exists.

```
DELETE FROM BIZ 
WHERE [Orgnl_Cmpltn_Date]
BETWEEN '2014-02-28'  AND '2014-04-01'
```

For a general idea of convert date:

```
DELETE FROM BIZ 
WHERE [Orgnl_Cmpltn_Date]
BETWEEN CONVERT(date,'2014.02.28',102) and CONVERT(date,'2014.04.01',102)
```

Here you can find the complete list of values for third parameter of `CONVERT`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: OH WOw! THanks Galma88. You are a genuis. That date does not exist.

Comment: This worked actually. Thank you. For future sake, how do I specify the date format

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Use this instead

```
DELETE FROM BIZ
WHERE [Orgnl_Cmpltn_Date] >= '2014-02-28'
AND [Orgnl_Cmpltn_Date] <= '2014'04'01'
```

I don't know if this matters, but February has only 28 or 29 days.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use SQL Server, try this..

```
    DELETE FROM BIZ 
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE,[Orgnl_Cmpltn_Date])
    BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,'2014-02-28') AND CONVERT(DATE,'2014-04-01')
```

Answer (score 1):

a couple of things

1) There is no such Date as February 31st, this could be a problem.

2) If you put your date range in the following format, you may have more luck:

```
BETWEEN '20140228'  AND '20140401'
```

Let me know how you get on :-)

Comment: that is a good date literal format for mssql, but not for other dbms,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
DELETE from Tabel_Name WHERE Date BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'01/01/2001',103) and CONVERT(datetime,'31/12/2001',103)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: please [edit] your answer to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.